# Throwing exception from CompletableFuture

Tags: java, exception, java-8, completable-future

I have the following code:

```
// How to throw the ServerException?
public void myFunc() throws ServerException{
    // Some code
    CompletableFuture<A> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            return someObj.someFunc();
        } catch(ServerException ex) {
            // throw ex; gives an error here.
        }
    }));
    // Some code
}
```

`someFunc()` throws a `ServerException`. I don't want to handle this here but throw the exception from `someFunc()` to caller of `myFunc()`.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Your code suggests that you are using the result of the asynchronous operation later in the same method, so you’ll have to deal with `CompletionException` anyway, so one way to deal with it, is

```
public void myFunc() throws ServerException {
    // Some code
    CompletableFuture<A> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try { return someObj.someFunc(); }
        catch(ServerException ex) { throw new CompletionException(ex); }
    });
    // Some code running in parallel to someFunc()

    A resultOfA;
    try {
        resultOfA = a.join();
    }
    catch(CompletionException ex) {
        try {
            throw ex.getCause();
        }
        catch(Error|RuntimeException|ServerException possible) {
            throw possible;
        }
        catch(Throwable impossible) {
            throw new AssertionError(impossible);
        }
    }
    // some code using resultOfA
}
```

All exceptions thrown inside the asynchronous processing of the `Supplier` will get wrapped into a `CompletionException` when calling `join`, except the `ServerException` we have already wrapped in a `CompletionException`.

When we re-throw the cause of the `CompletionException`, we may face unchecked exceptions, i.e. subclasses of `Error` or `RuntimeException`, or our custom checked exception `ServerException`. The code above handles all of them with a multi-catch which will re-throw them. Since the declared return type of `getCause()` is `Throwable`, the compiler requires us to handle that type despite we already handled all possible types. The straight-forward solution is to throw this actually impossible throwable wrapped in an `AssertionError`.

Alternatively, we could use an alternative result future for our custom exception:

```
public void myFunc() throws ServerException {
    // Some code
    CompletableFuture<ServerException> exception = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<A> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try { return someObj.someFunc(); }
        catch(ServerException ex) {
            exception.complete(ex);
            throw new CompletionException(ex);
        }
    });
    // Some code running in parallel to someFunc()

    A resultOfA;
    try {
        resultOfA = a.join();
    }
    catch(CompletionException ex) {
        if(exception.isDone()) throw exception.join();
        throw ex;
    }

    // some code using resultOfA
}
```

This solution will re-throw all “unexpected” throwables in their wrapped form, but only throw the custom `ServerException` in its original form passed via the `exception` future. Note that we have to ensure that `a` has been completed (like calling `join()` first), before we query the `exception` future, to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Guava has helper methods. Catch looks like this: Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(e.getCause()); throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());

Comment: @Holger excellent answer! one needs to block on join to catch and throw exceptions in async

Comment: @Holger: Why not use get() method? Wouldn't that simply the multi-catch block?

Comment: @Miguel `get` differs from `join` by wrapping exceptions in an `ExecutionException` instead of `CompletionException`. This provides no improvement to the `catch` side. It also requires the caller to handle `InterruptedException`, which makes it more complicated. Further, since a `Supplier` can’t throw a checked `ExecutionException`, it has to stay with `CompletionException`, then `get` will extract the cause and re-wrap it in an `ExecutionException`, which makes it less efficient. Not that performance matters much for the exceptional case. But `get` is worse than `join` in every aspect here.

Comment: how to test this code? mainly than catch part (CompletionException ex) ?

Answer (score 83):

For those looking for other ways on exception handling with completableFuture

Below are several ways for example handling Parsing Error to Integer:

**1. Using `handle` method** - which enables you to provide a default value on exception

```
CompletableFuture correctHandler = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "A")
            .thenApply(Integer::parseInt)
            .handle((result, ex) -> {
                if (null != ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("HANDLING " + result);
                    return result;
                }
            })
            .thenAcceptAsync(s -> {
                System.out.println("CORRECT: " + s);
            });
```

**2. Using `exceptionally` Method** - similar to `handle` but less verbose

```
CompletableFuture parser = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "1")
                .thenApply(Integer::parseInt)
                .exceptionally(t -> {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    return 0;
                }).thenAcceptAsync(s -> System.out.println("CORRECT value: " + s));
```

**3. Using `whenComplete` Method** - using this will stop the method on its tracks and not execute the next `thenAcceptAsync`

```
CompletableFuture correctHandler2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "A")
                .thenApply(Integer::parseInt)
                .whenComplete((result, ex) -> {
                    if (null != ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                })
                .thenAcceptAsync(s -> {
                    System.out.println("When Complete: " + s);
                });
```

**4. Propagating the exception via `completeExceptionally`**

```
public static CompletableFuture<Integer> converter(String convertMe) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        try {
            future.complete(Integer.parseInt(convertMe));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            future.completeExceptionally(ex);
        }
        return future;
    }
```

Comment: For those of you, like me, who are unable to use 1, 2 and 3 because of `CompletableFuture<Void>`, just return a `null` where an object of type `Void` is expected :) Took me hours to figure out this simple thing.

Answer (score 4):

Even if other's answer is very nice. but I give you another way to throw a checked exception in `CompletableFuture`.

**IF** you don't want to invoke a `CompletableFuture` in another thread, you can use an anonymous class to handle it like this:

```
CompletableFuture<A> a = new CompletableFuture<A>() {{
    try {
        complete(someObj.someFunc());
    } catch (ServerException ex) {
        completeExceptionally(ex);
    }
}};
```

**IF** you want to invoke a `CompletableFuture` in another thread, you also can use an anonymous class to handle it, but run method by `runAsync`:

```
CompletableFuture<A> a = new CompletableFuture<A>() {{
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            complete(someObj.someFunc());
        } catch (ServerException ex) {
            completeExceptionally(ex);
        }
    });
}};
```

Comment: There is no need to do that in an anonymous subclass at all. The subclass only wastes resources. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43767613/2711488) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28961083/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger thank you, sir. I only write it up in my mind. and I'll see it later.

Comment: @Holger sir, I found your two answers are different. and I prefer your first one that you used in this question. because it is easy to use and very clearly.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should wrap that into a `RuntimeException` and throw that:

```
 throw new RuntimeException(ex);
```

Or many be a small utility would help:

```
static class Wrapper extends RuntimeException {

    private Wrapper(Throwable throwable) {
        super(throwable);
    }

    public static Wrapper wrap(Throwable throwable) {
        return new Wrapper(throwable);
    }

    public Throwable unwrap() {
        return getCause();
    }
}


 public static void go() {
    CompletableFuture<String> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Just because");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw Wrapper.wrap(ex);
        }
    });

    a.join();
}
```

And then you could `unwrap` that..

```
 try {
        go();
 } catch (Wrapper w) {
        throw w.unwrap();
 }
```

Comment: I need to throw a `ServerException` only.

Comment: @ayushgp i don't see this happening with default streams, since they do not allow checked exceptions... may be you would be ok with wrapping that one and than unwrapping?

Comment: It looks like your `go()` method would never throw anything. I guess it's missing a `join()` call. Also, `Wrapper` does not provide much more than what's already available with `Throwable.getCause()`. I wouldn't wrap an exception into another one without setting the cause, as it breaks the convention and it will not print proper stacktraces.

Comment: @DidierL yes `go` was there just to prove a point, it's not very useful indeed. `Wrapper` on the other hand is here just to wrap the checked exception into a runtime one.

Comment: @Eugene I meant that in the current form of `go()`, your `try`/`catch` would never actually catch the `Wrapper`. I find it quite misleading. For `Wrapper` I meant you should call `super(Throwable)` instead of defining your own field, so that `printStackTrace()` and `getCause()` would behave as naturally expected from such a wrapper.