# How to throw a custom exception from CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future

Question: how can I directly throw a custom exception from `.exceptionally()`?

```
List<CompletableFuture<Object>> futures =
    tasks.stream()
        .map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> businessLogic(task))
        .exceptionally(ex -> {
                if (ex instanceof BusinessException) return null;

                //TODO how to throw a custom exception here??
                throw new BadRequestException("at least one async task had an exception");
        }))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

try {
    List<Object> results = futures.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (CompletionException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof RuntimeException) {
              throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
}
```

Problem: I just always get a `CompletionException` whose `ex.getCause()` is instanceof `BadRequestException`.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, every exception will be wrapped into a `CompletionException`

Comment: `CompletableFuture` will eventuall call `encodeThrowable(Throwable x)` where `x` is your exception and return `new AltResult((x instanceof CompletionException) ? x : new CompletionException(x));` - hence you'll always get a `CompletionException`. The only thing I see to directly get your exception would be to make it extend `CompletionException`.

Comment: So I'd have to wrap the code above in an additional `try {..} catch (CompletionException e)` and rethrow the underlying exception outside? Please see my update: that makes it very boilerplate, but there is probably no better solution?

Comment: You can also use `ex.addSuppressed(new BadRequestException("at least one async task had an exception"))` and then access `Arrays.stream(e.getSuppressed()).filter(...)`

Comment: Thb that's not less boilerplate...

Comment: Why are you constructing a new `RuntimeException` to wrap the cause, when the `CompletionException` is already a runtime exception wrapping the cause? Just use `catch(CompletionException e) { throw e.getCause() instanceof RuntimeException? (RuntimeException)e.getCause(): e; }`

Comment: Because the wrapped exception (=the cause) might not be a `RuntimeException`itself...

Comment: It looks like you missed the point of my comment. Throwing a `RuntimeException` wrapping whatever throwable is no improvement over throwing an `ExecutionException` wrapping the same throwable.

Comment: You just reversed your entire question. So you want to handle `BusinessException` by replacing with `null` and handle any other exception by throwing `BadRequestException`? That should be reflected by the `catch` clause as well. But just say… is this really what you want? It contradicts all your previous comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [said by Didier L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49035790/2711488), exceptions thrown by the functions (or generally [exceptions that completed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally-java.lang.Throwable-) a `CompletableFuture`) are always wrapped in a `CompletionException` (unless they are already a `CompletionException` or `CancellationException`).

But note that your code becomes much simpler when not even trying to translate the exception via `exceptionally`:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Object>> futures =
    tasks.stream()
        .map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> businessLogic(task)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
try {
    List<Object> results = futures.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (CompletionException e) {
    throw e.getCause() instanceof BusinessException?
        new BadRequestException("at least one async task had an exception"): e;
}
```

or

```
… catch (CompletionException e) {
    throw e.getCause() instanceof BusinessException?
        new BadRequestException("at least one async task had an exception"):
        e.getCause() instanceof RuntimeException rte? rte: e;
}
```

Since `exceptionally`’s primary purpose is translating an exception to a non-exceptional result value, using it for translating the exception to another thrown exception was not the best fit anyway and it also needed an `instanceof`. So performing this translation in the `catch` clause saves you from another translation step.

Comment: Well but as you see above I only want to rethrow the exception if instanceof `BusinessException', and ignore (=`return null`) otherwise in exceptionally.

Comment: In your question’s code, the `catch` clause rethrows all unexpected exceptions rather than swallowing them. Why do you want to substitute them with `null` at one place (not discussing the code smell of that), but rethrow at another? That’s inconsistent.

Comment: See that in `.exceptionally()` I'm swallowing any exceptions except `BusinessExecption`! Meaning: I want to ignore any exceptions but `BusinessExceptions`. Those should be rethrown outside of the future (and not being rethrown as a nested `CompletionException`). If I won't analyze the exception inside `.exceptionally()`, I would not be able to continue the futures if an exception can be ignored. Thus I cannot simply catch all of them outside.

Comment: Exactly. “any except a particular one” means “anything unexpected”, including `RuntimeException`s (indicating bugs) or `Error`s (indicating serious problems with the environment). Swallowing those is a big code smell. But besides that, these problems may also occur at other places in your chain than in the `Supplier`, hence may not get swallowed but rethrown by you `catch` clause. That’s inconsistent.

Comment: Ok I see the point. Then my example is maybe not chosen at it's best. So let me rewrite it that `BusinessException` is the one to be ignored, and all unexpected errors should be rethrown.

Comment: But that would be so easy to solve by wrapping `businessLogic` without needing any effort anywhere else: `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { try { return businessLogic(task); } catch(BusinessException ex) { return null; } })`… There’s no way how `CompletableFuture` could make that simpler.

Comment: Ok, I just thought catching and handling the exception should take place in `.exceptionall()`, and not in `supplyAsync()` itself.

Comment: That’s tricky, as the function passed to `exceptionally` receives a `Throwable`, but is only allowed to throw unchecked exceptions, so re-throwing is quiet limited. As said in the answer, `exceptionally` is intended to (always) replace an exception with a fall-back value rather than re-throwing. Building a re-throwing feature atop of that would be very complicated. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44411450/2711488).

Comment: Ok if so, I'm probably misusing `exceptionally()` here and will try-catch my businessexception inside the supplier directly.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. The [Javadoc of `join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--) clearly states:

> Returns the result value when complete, or throws an (unchecked)
>   exception if completed exceptionally. To better conform with the use
>   of common functional forms, **if a computation involved in the
>   completion of this CompletableFuture threw an exception, this method
>   throws an (unchecked) [`CompletionException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionException.html)** with the underlying
>   exception as its cause.

(emphasis is mine)