# CompletableFuture exception handling runAsync & thenRun

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, java-8, completable-future

Let's say I have this sample code and an exception is encountered inside `runAsync`. My question is would this exception prevent the `thenRun` from getting executed as `thenRun` runs in the same thread as the caller method of this code.

```
private void caller() {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
          try {
              // some code
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new CustomException(errorMessage, e);
          }
         }, anInstanceOfTaskExecutor).thenRun(
         // thenRun code
     ));
}
```

I already went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409962/throwing-exception-from-completablefuture) thread and it explains how you can handle exceptions thrown from asynchronous blocks (i.e. by blocking and using `join`). I want to know if code inside `thenRun` block would be executed or not if `CompletableFuture` `completesExceptionally`.

**Update**:

I ran some code to test this:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
      integerList.get(1);    // throws exception
    }).thenRun(() -> {
      System.out.println("No exception occurred");
    });
```

It does not print anything and it means exception didn't 'propagate up to/reach' the caller method's thread from the asynchronous block. I understand the expected behavior here now but I have following questions:

1. Why is it silently failing even though the CompletableFuture completesExceptionally?
2. How does it work in the background?
3. Is it because both these threads (caller's thread & asynchronous thread) have their own stack space?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## General Information

The documentation of [`CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) explains the general rules of the interface:

> A stage of a possibly asynchronous computation, that performs an action or computes a value when another `CompletionStage` completes. A stage completes upon termination of its computation, but this may in turn trigger other dependent stages. The functionality defined in this interface takes only a few basic forms, which expand out to a larger set of methods to capture a range of usage styles:

> - The computation performed by a stage may be expressed as a `Function`, `Consumer`, or `Runnable` (using methods with names including *apply*, *accept*, or *run*, respectively) depending on whether it requires arguments and/or produces results. For example:
>
>   ```java
>   stage.thenApply(x -> square(x))
>        .thenAccept(x -> System.out.print(x))
>        .thenRun(() -> System.out.println());
>   ```
>
> An additional form (*compose*) allows the construction of computation pipelines from functions returning completion stages.
>
> Any argument to a stage's computation is the outcome of a triggering stage's computation.
>
> - One stage's execution may be triggered by completion of a single stage, or both of two stages, or either of two stages. Dependencies on a single stage are arranged using methods with prefix *then*. Those triggered by completion of both of two stages may combine their results or effects, using correspondingly named methods. Those triggered by *either* of two stages make no guarantees about which of the results or effects are used for the dependent stage's computation.
> - Dependencies among stages control the triggering of computations, but do not otherwise guarantee any particular ordering. Additionally, execution of a new stage's computations may be arranged in any of three ways: default execution, default asynchronous execution (using methods with suffix *async* that employ the stage's default asynchronous execution facility), or custom (via a supplied `Executor`). The execution properties of default and async modes are specified by `CompletionStage` implementations, not this interface. Methods with explicit `Executor` arguments may have arbitrary execution properties, and might not even support concurrent execution, but are arranged for processing in a way that accommodates asynchrony.
> - Two method forms (`handle` and `whenComplete`) support unconditional computation whether the triggering stage completed normally or exceptionally. Method `exceptionally` supports computation only when the triggering stage completes exceptionally, computing a replacement result, similarly to the java *[sic]* `catch` keyword. In all other cases, if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a `CompletionException` holding the exception as its cause. If a stage is dependent on *both* of two stages, and both complete exceptionally, then the `CompletionException` may correspond to either one of these exceptions. If a stage is dependent on *either* of two others, and only one of them completes exceptionally, no guarantees are made about whether the dependent stage completes normally or exceptionally. In the case of method `whenComplete`, when the supplied action itself encounters an exception, then the stage completes exceptionally with this exception unless the source stage also completed exceptionally, in which case the exceptional completion from the source stage is given preference and propagated to the dependent stage.
>
> All methods adhere to the above triggering, execution, and exceptional completion specifications (which are not repeated in individual method specifications). *[...]*
>
> *[...]*

And documentation of [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) explains the threading rules (and other policies) where, as documented above, some of which are left up to the implementations of `CompletionStage`:

> A `Future` that may be explicitly completed (setting its value and status), and may be used as a `CompletionStage`, supporting dependent functions and actions that trigger upon its completion.
>
> When two or more threads attempt to `complete`, `completeExceptionally`, or `cancel` a `CompletableFuture`, only one of them succeeds.
>
> In addition to these and related methods for directly manipulating status and results, `CompletableFuture` implements interface `CompletionStage` with the following policies:
>
> - Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current `CompletableFuture`, or by any other caller of a completion method.
> - All async methods without an explicit `Executor` argument are performed using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new `Thread` is created to run each task). This may be overridden for non-static methods in subclasses by defining method `defaultExecutor()`. To simplify monitoring, debugging, and tracking, all generated asynchronous tasks are instances of the marker interface `CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask`. Operations with time-delays can use adapter methods defined in this class, for example: `supplyAsync(supplier, delayedExecutor(timeout, timeUnit))`. To support methods with delays and timeouts, this class maintains at most one daemon thread for triggering and cancelling actions, not for running them.
> - All `CompletionStage` methods are implemented independently of other public methods, so the behavior of one method is not impacted by overrides of others in subclasses.
> - All `CompletionStage` methods return `CompletableFuture`s. To restrict usages to only those methods defined in interface `CompletionStage`, use method `minimalCompletionStage()`. Or to ensure only that clients do not themselves modify a future, use method `copy()`.
>
> `CompletableFuture` also implements `Future` with the following policies:
>
> - Since (unlike `FutureTask`) this class has no direct control over the computation that causes it to be completed, cancellation is treated as just another form of exceptional completion. Method `cancel` has the same effect as `completeExceptionally(new CancellationException())`. Method `isCompletedExceptionally()` can be used to determine if a `CompletableFuture` completed in any exceptional fashion.
> - In case of exceptional completion with a `CompletionException`, methods `get()` and `get(long, TimeUnit)` throw an `ExecutionException` with the same cause as held in the corresponding `CompletionException`. To simplify usage in most contexts, this class also defines methods `join()` and `getNow(T)` that instead throw the `CompletionException` directly in these cases.
>
> *[...]*

---

## Your Questions

Here's your example code:

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
      integerList.get(1);    // throws exception
    }).thenRun(() -> {
      System.out.println("No exception occurred");
    });
```

If you aren't aware, methods such as `thenRun` return a *new* `CompletionStage`. So your code is similar to the following:

```java
CompletableFuture<Void> runAsyncStage = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> List.of().get(0));
CompletableFuture<Void> thenRunStage =
    runAsyncStage.thenRun(() -> System.out.println("thenRun executing!"));
```

The `thenRunStage` is triggered by the completion of the `runAsyncStage` which, in this case, is guaranteed to complete exceptionally with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. As for why the `Runnable` isn't executed, that's due to the contract of [`CompletionStage#thenRun(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenRun(java.lang.Runnable)):

> Returns a new `CompletionStage` that, when this stage completes normally, executes the given action. See the `CompletionStage` documentation for rules covering exceptional completion.

Due to the triggering stage completing exceptionally the `thenRunStage` stage also completes exceptionally, which means the `Runnable` is skipped.

### 1. "Why is it silently failing even though the CompletableFuture completesExceptionally?"

The example code is the equivalent of swallowing an exception with a try-catch block. You don't see the exception because you haven't written code that would report the exception. Both the `runAsyncStage` and `thenRunStage` stages have completed exceptionally, the latter because of the former completing exceptionally.

If you want to be aware of the exception "within the chain" of stages then you have to use stages such as `exceptionally[Async]`, `handle[Async]`, and `whenComplete[Async]`. Doing it this way allows you to change the behavior of the chain based on normal or exceptional completion of a trigger stage.

If you want to be aware of the exception "outside the chain" of stages then you have to use methods such as `join()`, `get()`, and `get(long,TimeUnit)`. If the stage had completed exceptionally then the first will throw a `CompletionException` wrapping the cause-of-failure while the latter two will throw an `ExecutionException` wrapping the cause-of-failure.

### 2. "How does it work in the background?"

The implementation of `CompletableFuture` is too complex to explain in a Stack Overflow answer. If you want to study the implementation you can look at the source code. Your JDK should have come with a `src.zip` file containing the Java source files. You can also look at the source code online in the [OpenJDK repositories](https://github.com/openjdk). For instance, here's the source code of `CompletableFuture`:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java

### 3. "Is it because both these threads (caller's thread & asynchronous thread) have their own stack space?"

One thread will not be aware of an exception in another thread unless there's some sort of communication between the two threads. Calling methods such as `join()` will, when appropriate, communicate the exception to the calling thread which will throw said exception. However, as shown by the answer to your first question, it's slightly more complicated than that. Even when a thread throws an exception *within a single stage* you won't see a stack trace or anything similar. This is because the exception is *caught* and the stage is marked as failed *with that exception as the cause*. Other code then has to explicitly retrieve and handle that exception, as needed.

This is no different than using an `ExecutorService` and returned `Future` objects. The task may fail in the background, but other code won't be aware of that until the `Future` is queried.

### From bounty: “I am looking to understand the details of how threads interact with each other.”

I'm not sure what else to add. The `CompletionStage` API is an abstraction "above" threads. You simply tell the API how you would like the chain of commands to execute, including which thread pools to use for each stage, and the implementation handles all the inter-thread communication for you. That said, each thread does it's own thing, it's just the API is designed to provide an easier and reactive way to communicate between threads. If you're interested in *how* that's implemented then I recommend studying the source code (linked above).

Answer (score 5):

It will depend on which step you are adding `exceptionally`.

In the below case, it will skip `thenRun` and directly execute exceptionally block.

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { 
     //process and throw exception
     }, anInstanceOfTaskExecutor )
    .thenRun(() -> {})
    .exceptionally(exception -> {
      // do something, handle exception
    })
 ));
```

In this case, it will execute `thenRun`.

```
   CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { 
     //process and throw exception
     }, anInstanceOfTaskExecutor )
    .exceptionally(exception -> {
      // do something, handle exception
    })
    .thenRun(() -> {})
 ));
```

I hope, it helps

Comment: Thanks @lucid. Would you happen to know why is this the expected behavior? Why would thenRun block be skipped asynchronous code block completesExceptionally?

Comment: you can check 4th point in the official documentation. that will help understanding inner working. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html

Comment: @Miguel Because some stages are only applicable to normal completion (e.g. `thenRun`), other stages are only applicable to exceptional completion (e.g. `exceptionally`), and yet other stages are applicable to either (e.g. `handle`). How stages are invoked depends on the built chain of stages. In your question's example, the `thenRun` stage completes exceptionally because its triggering stage competed exceptionally; the `Runnable` is not executed in this case because the contract of `thenRun` states the `Runnable` will only be executed if the triggering stage completes normally.